# CSV import encoding

Tags: php, encoding, csv

I'm importing a CSV using the `fgetcsv()` function, which is working all good.

However, when I take a look at the data in the database, I see black diamonds with question marks. This isn't too much of an issue when echoing the data back out again, as they don't appear, but when I want to use one of the CSV fields as a MySQL date, it isn't recognised as a date and is stored as `0000-00-00`.

e.g.

[image]

I think this issue is something to do with encoding of the CSV? Can anyone offer any advice?

Thanks!

Edit: if it helps here is my import script, and the encode type is ASCII according to mb_detect_encoding

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$row = 0;
$tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

if (($handle = fopen($tmpName, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);

     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
        $noQuotes = str_replace("\"", '', $data);
        $originalDate = $noQuotes[1];

        //$delivery_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($originalDate));

        $parts = explode('/', $originalDate);
        $delivery_date = $parts[2] . '-' . $parts[1] . '-' . $parts[0];

        $row++;

        $import="INSERT into dispatch (delivery_note_number, delivery_date, dispatch_date, customer_delivery_date, delivery_line, produce, variety, quantity, pallets, count, depot, customer, grower, haulier, status) 
        values ('$noQuotes[0]', '$delivery_date', '$noQuotes[2]', '$noQuotes[3]', '$noQuotes[4]', '$noQuotes[5]', '$noQuotes[6]', '$noQuotes[7]', '$noQuotes[8]', '$noQuotes[9]', '$noQuotes[10]', '$noQuotes[11]', '$noQuotes[12]', '$noQuotes[13]', '$noQuotes[14]')";

        echo $import; 
        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
     }

        //header("location:list_dispatch.php?st=recordsadded");


    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

Comment: are you maybe not using utf-8 encoding? Are you storing the date filed as dates?

Comment: do a hex dump of the value, or even better, post here the output of `base64_encode($date);`. this gives us a binary perfect clone of your data, and can help someone identify those stray bytes. Maybe utf16?

Comment: base64_encode output is ADIAMAAxADIALQAwADEALQAwADQA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone found a solution on a another forum:

> Those are NUL characters (ASCII code 0x00), replace them like this:
>
> $string = str_replace(chr(0), '', $string);

Answer (score 2):

If your database is using a different character encoding than the CSV file, it is possible the data should converted first.

One way to perform this is using the [mb_convert_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function.

Also useful, [mb_detect_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) should be able to detect the character encoding for a given input string.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding for the field returns type ASCII

Answer (score 0):

```
fputcsv($f, $array, ' ', chr(0));
```